# Gradle always downloads dependencies with latest version

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies

I have an app that uses 'library 1' and 'library 2' . Let's say library1 uses coil version-1(an image library for example) and library2 uses coil version 2... when implementing both library 1 and library 2 in my app... only the latest version of coil i.e., coil version 2 is downloaded... is there any way to mitigate this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot have `library1` using `coil` version-1 and `library2` using `coil` version-2. Possible approaches:

1. Do nothing, only works if `library1` works with `coil` version-2.
2. Force the coil dependency to be version-1.  Only works if `library2` works with `coil` version-1.
3. Use an older version of `library2` which has a dependency on `coil` version-1.
4. Find an alternative library to `library1` which uses a more recent version of `coil`.

Comment: "AFAIK you cannot have library1 using coil version-1 and library2 using coil version-2." can you tell me why . Like I am just curious to know why such constrained dependency is not allowed. Also is there any workaround to solve this using gradle or something.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want coil version-1 ?
Graddle always download newest version of the dependency by default.

Comment: let's say i use a api from coil-1 which is removed in coil-2 in library1, it makes a runtime error in the app.